# Android alarmManager.setAlarmClock Crash Android 7

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am getting a crash (on android 7 only) when calling alarmmanager.setAlarmClock in a function where i am setting alarm. I have no idea what is wrong here. And how to fix this
crash.

This is the function which is getting crash when calling alarmManager.setAlarmClock

```
fun setBeforeAlert(
        context: Context,
        offset: Long,
        beforeMin: Int,
        pendingIntent: PendingIntent
    ) {
        if (offset - beforeMin * 60 * 1000 > 0) {
            val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                val alarmClockInfo = AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo((System.currentTimeMillis() + offset) - beforeMin * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent)
                alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pendingIntent)
            }
            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (System.currentTimeMillis() + offset) - beforeMin * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent)
            }
            else {
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (System.currentTimeMillis() + offset) - beforeMin * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the pending intent which i am passing to above function:

```
val intent = Intent(context, AlertAlarm::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(Constants.key_alert_alarm_code, reqCode)
        intent.putExtra(Constants.key_alert_type, type)
        intent.putExtra(Constants.key_alert_min, min)
        val pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, reqCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

This is the crash report i am getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.android.server.AlarmManagerService$Batch.size()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3377)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6802)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.android.server.AlarmManagerService$Batch.size()' on a null object reference
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1714)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1661)
at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set(IAlarmManager.java:246)
at android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl(AlarmManager.java:680)
at android.app.AlarmManager.setAlarmClock(AlarmManager.java:601)
at com.mypackage.util.AlarmUtils.setBeforeAlert(AlarmUtils.kt:42)
at com.com.mypackage.util.AzanUtils.setBeforeAlertAlarms(AzanUtils.kt:358)
at com.com.mypackage.util.AzanUtils.setAlarms(AzanUtils.kt:160)
```

Comment: You can use the Work manager instead of the alarm manager. Work Manage uses an Alarm manger or Job scheduler based on the current app requirement.

Answer (score 5):

We also get the same crash on OPPO devices (Android 7). If you look at `size()` method in `AlarmManagerService.Batch.class`, it NEVER should be a null. I assume some manufacturers have changed the implementation of the `IAlarmManager (AlarmManagerService)` which is causing the problem. You can't do anything about it.

Comment: Can't we really get any workaround about this? Can't we do try-catch and try again if crash?

Comment: so i isolate that device with private fun exclude() =
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1 && "CPH1727" == Build.MODEL :)

Answer (score -2):

Be sure your `alarmManager` is not null, like following.

```
val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
if (alarmManager != null){
  // do your stuff here.
}
```

Comment: Is there a possibility it could return null, error? why?

Comment: alarmmanager is not null. if we see the crash report from bottom to top you can see its crashing at:
android.app
.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set(IAlarmManager.java:246
)

Comment: if alarmmanager is null, android will be throw npe on other line, ndroid.app.AlarmManager.setAlarmClock(AlarmManager.java:601)

Answer (score -2):

You need to make sure alarmManager is not null i.e.system allowed you to use AlarmService. Add a simple null check and make casting nullable.

```
    val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as? AlarmManager
    if (alarmManager != null){
        // set alarm using setExact or setAlarmClock
    } else {
        //  failed to get alarm service, show error
    }
```

Comment: alarmmanager is not null. if we see the crash report from bottom to top you can see its crashing at:
android.app
.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set(IAlarmManager.java:246
)

Comment: It can be null. In cases, os does not allow your app to use AlarmService, it returns null to getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)  call. You need to add check to ensure you get instance of alarm manager and then use it.

Comment: if alarmmanager is null, android will be throw npe on other line, ndroid.app.AlarmManager.setAlarmClock(AlarmManager.java:601)